# Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'. in coreUI template

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

When i run  the command : `ng serve -o` i have this error :

ERROR in src/app/views/base/navbars/navbars.component.ts:2:33 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-bootstrap'.
Line 2: import {CollapseDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

this is my package.json file :

```
{
  ..............

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "^2.9.0",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "0.3.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^9.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.20",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.20",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.900.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.34",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10",
    "npm": ">= 6"
  }
}
```

in fact, the module works correctly in another computer. but when I used git to work at home, I can't execute the project.

Comment: please put package.json  and app.module code

Comment: there is still no package.json

Comment: @Çağrı  it's done

Comment: Can u downgrade your ngx-bootsrap as below answer

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually angular 9 does not support

" import {CollapseDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap" kind of import.
you should import from the child directory like
" import {CollapseDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse'"

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer and doesn't add anything new

Answer (score 3):

As I see from your package.json, your angular version is 9.

So, you should use ngx-boostrap as wrote in their official document. See below how you should import in Angular 9:

RECOMMENDED:

> import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';

NOT RECOMMENDED (**Angular 9 doesn't support this kind of import**):

> import { CollapseModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

Answer (score 0):

In package json change ngx-botsrap version

```
"ngx-bootstrap": "5.3.2"
```

then run `npm install`

then build project

and write

```
 import {CollapseDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse'
```

Comment: my version  is  "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0"

Comment: can u try this one

Comment: ```import {CollapseDirective} from 'ngx-bootstrap/collapse';```  can u change your import with this